# Guesslangtools: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'timeout'

Tags: python

I'm using [Guesslangtools](https://github.com/yoeo/guesslangtools) on my Mac in order to create a dataset.

When the execution reaches the step "Download chosen repositories" I'm hitting the following error:

Could this error be in any way related to Python 9?

I would appreciate suggestions on how to fix this.

````
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/guesslangtools/common.py", line 264, in _apply
    return method(item, *other_args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/guesslangtools/workflow/github_repositories.py", line 130, in _clone_repository
    result = run(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 505, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1821, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'timeout'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/gltool", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/guesslangtools/__main__.py", line 153, in main
    run_workflow(config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/guesslangtools/app.py", line 15, in run_workflow
    github_repositories.download(config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/guesslangtools/common.py", line 175, in wrapped
    result = func(config, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/guesslangtools/workflow/github_repositories.py", line 105, in download
    for step, row in enumerate(pool_map(_clone_repository, rows, config), 1):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/guesslangtools/common.py", line 255, in pool_map
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(_apply, iterable):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 870, in next
    raise value
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'timeout'```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it’s likely because the GNU timeout program does not exist on the system that is running the test. timeout is part of the GNU Coreutils, so make sure that is installed on the system.

```
$ brew install coreutils  # Mac OS X
```

then add a "gnubin" directory to your PATH, for example:

```
$ export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/coreutils/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
```

Comment: that's my pleasure!